# Find matching object property in array and merge into new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects, where I want to find the objects having same value for **name** property and then merge them into single object by adding their values & subvalues.

```
const arr = [
 { id: 1, name: 'a', value: 2, subvalue: 3 }, 
 { id: 2, name: 'b', value: 4, subvalue: 3 },
 { id: 3, name: 'c', value: 4, subvalue: 3 },
 { id: 4, name: 'b', value: 3, subvalue: 4 } 
]
```

Expected output

```
[
 { id: 1, name: 'a', value: 2, subvalue: 3 }, 
 { id: 2, name: 'b', value: 7, subvalue: 7 },
 { id: 3, name: 'c', value: 4, subvalue: 3 }
]
```

The id of the new object can either be 2 or it can be 4. So it doesn't matter much. I have tried using filter, but not able to find a solution which suits my requirement

Comment: Using `filter` alone won't solve this task, see my answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: or [Javascript array of objects group and sum items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65059071/javascript-array-of-objects-group-and-sum-items) or [Grouping an Array and then summing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68339586/grouping-an-array-and-then-summing-values) or [How to group by and sum an array of objects javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72314939/how-to-group-by-and-sum-an-array-of-objects-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `reduce` to group by `name` and then get the values array of the grouped object using `Object.values`

```js
const arr = [
 { id: 1, name: 'a', value: 2, subvalue: 3 }, 
 { id: 2, name: 'b', value: 4, subvalue: 3 },
 { id: 3, name: 'c', value: 4, subvalue: 3 },
 { id: 4, name: 'b', value: 3, subvalue: 4 } 
]

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  if(!acc[curr.name]){
    acc[curr.name] = curr
  } else {
    acc[curr.name].value += curr.value
    acc[curr.name].subvalue += curr.subvalue
  }
  return acc
},{}))

console.log(res)
```

or the whole if else logic be one-lined but less readable

```js
const arr = [
 { id: 1, name: 'a', value: 2, subvalue: 3 }, 
 { id: 2, name: 'b', value: 4, subvalue: 3 },
 { id: 3, name: 'c', value: 4, subvalue: 3 },
 { id: 4, name: 'b', value: 3, subvalue: 4 } 
]

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.name] = acc[curr.name] ? {...acc[curr.name], value: acc[curr.name].value + curr.value, subvalue: acc[curr.name].subvalue + curr.subvalue} : curr
    return acc
}, {}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: You really posted a new group by answer?

Answer (score 1):

Using only [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), see if the `name` of the `curr`ent object is already present in the `acc`umulator with [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), then *Values* and *Subvalues* should be accumulated respectively with the current object *Values* and *Subvalues*, Otherwise add the current `obj`ect in the `acc`umulator:

```js
const arr = [ { id: 1, name: 'a', value: 2, subvalue: 3 }, { id: 2, name: 'b', value: 4, subvalue: 3 }, { id: 3, name: 'c', value: 4, subvalue: 3 }, { id: 4, name: 'b', value: 3, subvalue: 4 } ];
const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex((obj) => obj.name === cur.name);
  if (index !== -1) {
    acc[index] = {
      ...acc[index],
      value: acc[index].value + cur.value,
      subvalue: acc[index].subvalue + cur.subvalue,
    };
  } else {
    acc.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

if you don't want to maintain the first *(original)* `id` and would rather use the id from the last *(most recent)* merged object, just replace  `...acc[index]` with `...cur` when you merge them.